# When there is elimination and when there is nucleophilic substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am studying organic chemistry for quite a time now, but this is the general problem I come across. Both seems likely. I only know that heat causes elimination, but this does not appear to be the only reason always. So I want a complete reference.

Comment: I edited your question, also “You should never ask anyone for anything. Never- and especially from those who are more powerful than yourself.”
― Mikhail Bulgakov, The Master and Margarita

Comment: @Mith If that were right, then Chem.SE wouldn't exist ;)

Comment: @paracetamol There would be no homework, where OP are asking for answer, not posting good questions for everyone.

Comment: @Mith Point... but there wouldn't be *any* questions here to begin with :D

Comment: Stating a question and asking for answer are two different things. There's a lot difference between homework dump and Q&A. Also comments are not for prolonged discussions ;) We can continue in Chat

Answer (score 6):

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=substitution%20vs%20elimination) provides several sites that address this challenging topic in organic chemistry in detail. Additionally, most organic chemistry textbooks spend several pages on the matter.

Here's a summary of the conditions that favor each mechanism:

- $S_N 2$ reactions work best with methyl and primary substrates in polar aprotic solvents. Good nucleophiles are needed.
- $S_N 1$ reactions work best with tertiary substrates in polar protic solvents. Nucleophiles can be anything, but strong base or heat tends to suggest elimination.
- $E1$ reactions work best with tertiary substrates in polar protic solvents. Generally, no other reagent but the solvent is given (solvolysis) and the reaction is heated.
- $E2$ reactions work best with tertiary substrates in polar protic solvents. A strong base is required, and generally it is the conjugate base of the solvent. These reactions are often heated.

Or we can break it down by substrate type:

- Methyl substrates can only do $S_N 2$ reactions.
- Primary substrates will do $S_N 2$ with strong nucleophiles in aprotic solvents and $E2$ reactions with strong bases in protic solvents. All other substitution/elimination conditions react so slowly as to be **no reaction**.
- Tertiary substrates will do $S_N 1$ in protic solvents with weak bases, $E1$ in protic solvents with weak bases when heated, and $E2$ in protic solvents with strong bases. Substrates that generate resonance stabilized cations will behave like tertiary substrates.

> What about secondary?

Secondary substrates are where you need to start looking for clues:

- $S_N 2$ - polar aprotic solvent
- $S_N 1$ - protic solvent weak base
- $E2$ - protic solvent strong base
- $E1$ - protic solvent and heat

Alcohols in the presence of strong acid generally prefer the $S_N 1$ and $E1$ mechanisms.